# How to put ads in Chrome custom tambs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

using android Webview i'm able to size the height of a web page in my android app so i can put and ad below the webview and it works well but now i want to use Chrome custom tabs and they always use all the screen so  i cannot put an add below it, my question is: is there a way to resize the space that custom tabs occupies or to add an ad at the bottom of it?

Comment: `WebView` is a component that you have inside an `Activity`. Chrome custom tabs is an `Activity` itself. You can't modify that `Activity` or resize it

Comment: is there a way to add an ad at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can stick to WebView, it's highly customizable now than four years back. Or consider using Progressive Web App. This site may be helpful. https://web.dev/what-are-pwas/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31657021)